# Click a checkbox using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am trying to select the Checkbox for the following :

I tried with different xpath, id, css_selector but none of them worked out for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-ruleid="21FE54AC-1667-46sdC7-85A9-1540548AD6B9@@notable@@f7b515fasd1cf132c545d2cce4970bebf2b"').click()
```

Code for reference :

```
<label class="checkbox ir-label-checkbox">
   <a data-ruleid="21FE5fs4AC-1667-46C7-85A9-1540548AD6B9@@notable@@f7b515f1cf132c5sas45d2cce4970bebf2b" data-status="4" class="btn show"></a>
</label>
```

Comment: Please don't link images to code, input the code into the question instead.

Comment: @GiftZwergrapper : Done

Comment: The problem could easily be (and probably is) from the `""` at the end of your string

Comment: you don't need double `""` . it is not part of ID.

Comment: Is there more than one checkbox on the page? What else is around this element that we can use to form a locator? Include more of the surrounding HTML. Have you tried anything with the `data-status` attribute? What else have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following xpath:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn show'][1]").click()
```

2nd xpath for whole class:-

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='checkbox ir-label-checkbox'][1]").click()
```

3rd xpath:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(" //a[@class='btn show'][1]/@data-ruleid").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `Xpath`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='checkbox ir-label-checkbox']/a[@class='btn show']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using quotes in that way.

Yours:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@data-ruleid=""21FE54AC-1667-46sdC7-85A9-1540548AD6B9@@notable@@f7b515fasd1cf132c545d2cce4970bebf2b""').click()
```

With what I think is proper quoting (cannot test, this is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@data-ruleid='21FE54AC-1667-46sdC7-85A9-1540548AD6B9@@notable@@f7b515fasd1cf132c545d2cce4970bebf2b'").click()
```

Comment: Quotes "" was a typo i had tried earlier with removing them and it didn't work either.

Comment: @amitpanjawani Well you would need to include the link the the site you are trying this on for us to be able to test it ourselves and make sure it works...

Comment: I understand it would quick and easy if I share the site but apologies, I cannot share due to privacy. I can provide you any further details, if you need.

Comment: @amitpanjawani Well I am sorry, but we cannot help really any more than we already have without having access to the website. Best of luck in figuring it out!

Comment: No worries @Reedinationer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `//a[start-with(@data-ruleid,'21FE5fs4AC')]`. If it does not work then check the your HTML code and make sure that the code is static in nature or replace '21FE5fs4AC' this to the static and unique value.